# Construction with "wollen" and Perfekt

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verb, perfect-tense

I was reading Calvin and Hobbes comics in German and I've found the following dialogue:

Calvin: Irgendwelche Monster unter meinem Bett?!

Monster: Nein! Nöo!

Calvin: **Will ich euch auch nicht geraten haben!** Tät mir leid, wenn ich eins mit meinem Flammenwerfer abfackeln müsste!

How does one translate and analyse the sentence in bold? Could someone give examples of other phrases with wollen + Perfekt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does one translate [...] the sentence in bold?

Let me add "I wouldn't have advised you to be there" to [Marvin's suggestions](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/62470/39628).

> How does one [...] analyse the sentence in bold?

It seems to me that grammatically, the sentence behaves like the *Futur 2* tense. One can grammatically simplify the sentence to "Ich will geraten haben" (I want to have advised), whereas in *Futur 2*, it would be "Ich werde geraten haben" (I will have advised).

In meaning, the two differ significantly: The latter means that there will be a point in time in the future where something had happened before. The former means that I want for something to have happened before now.

> Could someone give examples of other phrases with wollen + Perfekt?

The concept can theoretically be generalized to all verbs: "Ich will gegessen haben" (I want to have eaten), "Ich will gefahren sein" (I want to have driven), but I should note that even though these examples are grammatically correct, they would probably never be used. Instead, one would probably say "Ich hätte essen sollen" (I should have eaten) and "Ich hätte fahren sollen" (I should have driven). My guess is that only one specific saying using this form, namely "Das will ich euch auch nicht geraten haben" has survived to this day.

Answer (score 1):

To have it as a more understandable sentence, you could have it as "*[Das] will ich euch auch nicht geraten haben*", where "Das" refers to the hiding which the monsters are doing.
Literally, it would perhaps read "*I wouldn't have wished that for you*". Meaning, more liberally, "*You'd better not be!*" or "*For your sake, I hope you aren't hiding under the bed*."